# Swift Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject!' and 'String!'

Tags: swift, object, parse-platform

I'd like to add the current user's username at the end of the object `Participants` in Parse using Swift but I got the error in the title.

```
obj["Participants"] += kCurrentUser.username
```

I don't know how to fix it. I have already tried `.append` and some other methods. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like obj is an NSDictionary. NSDictionaries contain anonymous values for each key. So when you look up a key, the value is of type AnyObject. You can't append a string to an AnyObject.

You'll have to use a more verbose statement:

```
obj["Participants"] = obj["Participants"] as! String + kCurrentUser.username
```

(That will only work if obj is a mutable dictionary. If it's immutable, it will crash.)

Comment: It'll also crash if `obj` has no value for the key `"Participants"` or if it has a value and that value can't be interpreted as a `String`, so perhaps let's not abuse the `!` operator?

Comment: I suspect that `obj["Participants"]` might be an array instead (he mentions that he tried `.append` plus `Participants` is a good name for a collection) and he tries to append a string in it (as opposed to reassignment)...

Comment: In this statement, isn’t the first `!` superfluous? since you are already using the `!` to unwrap it as a `String`?

Comment: @milo526, yes, I guess the first `!` isn't needed.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Whoever downvoted me, can you explain where you think my answer is wrong, misleading, or insufficient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006573/swift-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-anyobject-an/30006891#comment48132530_30006891 For the downvote

Comment: @nhgrif, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: My second comment points back to my first comment which explains downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Swift language does not do implicit conversion, if two operands of different type, you have to convert any one of them to the other operand type to apply the binary operator.

So in your case convert the operand which is of AnyObject type to String.

Answer (score 0):

Only couple of weeks into swift was hit by this but as mentioned "Swift Language doesn't do implicit type conversion,.."

For me I had this code:

```
if objects == nil {
  objects = NSMutableArray()
}
```

Converted to:

```
if objects.count == 0 {
  objects = NSMutableArray()
}
```